# how acess the report column value in oracle-apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I need the "elabora prenotazione" button to be shown only when the column "stato prenotazione" is "IN SOSPESO"
I tried to set a condition but I don't know how to pick the column value

[image]

Comment: Ivano, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, so we can check out what i've tried an a way to help you out.

Comment: Do you mean the **link** "elabora prenotazione"?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, this could help:

For the source of your report:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN stato_prenotazione = 'in sospeso' THEN 'elabora prenotazione'
        ELSE ''
    END name_of_column,
prenotazione,
username,
nome,
cognome,
viaggio,
stato_viaggio,
data_prenota,
stato_prenotazione,
numero_ospiti
FROM your_table
```

Then set the column "name_of_column" to type: link, and fill the target.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a condition around a call to apex_page.get_url within your SQL, so it will only produce a link when relevant

Example of function in use, sans condition:
https://azureoutput.wordpress.com/2017/10/18/custom-hyperlink-in-interactive-report/

Use this to make the button look prettier, and maybe get some other ideas
https://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/12/tutorial-include-action-button-in-report.html

See this in regard to escaping special characters, otherwise you'll just see HTML in your report
https://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2017/01/escape-special-characters-apex-demo.html

Answer (score 0):

This could be resolved by a simple case statement as @sara mentioned. 
something like:

`select (case stato_prenotazione when 'in sospeso' then 'elabora prenotazione' end) as your_column`

I would not keep else condition so that the column will simply contain null value if the condition is not met.